# How to create new column from existing column using split and join in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data ,

```
df=

ID  Grade_Levels
1     2|3|4
2     1|2
3     5|6|7
4     8|9|10
```

I want to create a column "Grade" that will have information from "Grade_Levels",

```
ID  Grade_Levels       Grade
1     2|3|4     Grade 2 Grade 3 Grade 4 
2     1|2       Grade 1 Grade 2 
3     5|6|7     Grade 5 Grade 6 Grade 7
4     8|9|10    Grade 8 Grade 9 Grade 10
```

How to do this in python for pandas data frame? Kindly help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: Do you want this `df["Grade"] = "Grade " + df["Grade_Levels"].str.replace("|", " Grade ")`?

Comment: @Dan, yup, I deleted my comment when I saw it

Comment: Thanks Dan. This works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply` method for this:

```
def split_and_join(row):
    grade_levels = row['Grade_Levels']
    return ' '.join(['Grade %s' % g for g in grade_levels.split('|')])

df['Grade'] = df.apply(split_and_join, axis=1)
```